Would donations count as revenue from a free software?
I would like to release a free and open source game that uses Unreal Engine. Aside from the licensing issues, there is also the question of royalties.
A commercial game using Unreal Engine must pay 5% royalties (past the first $1 million USD of gross revenue).
Would donations received for the development of an open source game count as revenue from that game, and be subject to the obligation to pay royalties for the engine?


Would donations received for the development of an open source game count as revenue from that game, and be subject to the obligation to pay royalties for the engine?

Based on the Unreal Engine EULA, it you make money, including donations, that is related to giving people access to the game (including money provided for developing the game) or giving people in-game benefits, then you must pay royalties.
As I understand the EULA, donations that you receive for making enhancements to an already published game are not considered part of the revenue and can be ignored for the royalty calculation.
For paying the royalties, there is a lifetime revenue threshold of USD 1.000.000,00 and a monthly revenue threshold of USD 10.000,00. Below those thresholds, no royalties are due.

Thanks for the answer. Re-reading the EULA, I found this: "The following are also excluded from the calculation of Royalty Revenue: [...]  revenue from donations for a Product that are not tied to Royalty Product access or in-Royalty Product benefits". Not sure but I think they mean donations for another product are excluded (which is a bit weird to mention actually). Not sure I'm understanding this right, but if I do, it would implicitly means that donations for the "Royalty Product" do count as revenue (even though getting access to it is independent to donating money or not).

I wonder what happens if someone forks the game and starts perceiving donations or other revenue for that fork. For an open-source game, I have absolutely no control over this. Notably, how would this work with revenue thresholds?

Also you said "donations that you receive for making enhancements to an already published game are not considered part of the revenue and can be ignored for the royalty calculation", what part of the EULA makes you say this?

@youen, I read that quote from the EULA differently, in that I believe that Product and Royalty Product refer to the same thing. That is also my basis for the belief that donations for enhancements are not part of the revenue.

@youen The way I read it "donations" that give the donor in-game perks (exclusive or early access, coins, items, etc) count for royalty calculation, this is likely to prevent high-earning devs from claiming their IAPs & DLCs are just "donor incentives". Bog standard donation that only serves as motivation for further development accessible by anyone doesn't count in royalty calculation.
